# Editing the style of xctk:DoubleUpDown Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpf-style, wpf-extended-toolkit

I like to change the Corner Radius of the xctk:DoubleUpDown Control to 2.
The following code does not work.
Without the Control Template Part no error is shown, but with the "Setter Property Template part" the error "73 Undefined `CLR-namespace´ URI to a namespace ´Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Themes` that could not be found."
is displayed.

Fontfamily, Fontsize, BorderThickness, Foreground are working.

Thank you for any help.

```
<xCtrl:ToolPanel 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:xCtrl="clr-namespace:XRayOfficeCore.GUI.Wpf;assembly=XRayOfficeCore"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" x:Class="EmitterGUI.StandardGUIPanel"
        xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Themes;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"    
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="564" Height="362">

    <xCtrl:ToolPanel.Resources>

   <Style TargetType="xctk:DoubleUpDown">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFC7CACC"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Frutiger LT Com 45 Light"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DoubleUpDown}">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

 </xCtrl:ToolPanel.Resources>
<Grid> 
(...)
</Grid>
</xCtrl:ToolPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

xctk:DoubleUpDown inherite from UpDownBase (not directly)
and it exppected that the following pars will be in the control template

See base class TemplatePart attributes:

```
 [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Spinner", Type = typeof (Spinner))]
 [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_TextBox", Type = typeof (TextBox))]
 public abstract class UpDownBase<T> : InputBase, IValidateInput
```